# How to measure the execution time of GPU with using Profiling+openCL+Sycl+DPCPP

Tags: gpu, profiling, opencl, sycl, dpc++

I read this link
https://github.com/intel/pti-gpu

and I tried to use Device Activity Tracing for OpenCL(TM), but I am confused and I do not know how should I measure the time on the accelerators with using Device Activity documentation.
for measuring the performance of CPU I used chrono, but I am interested in to using profiling for measuring the performance of CPU and GPU in different devices.
my program:

```
    #include <CL/sycl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include<tbb/blocked_range.h>
#include <tbb/global_control.h>
#include <chrono>


using namespace tbb;

template<class Tin, class Tout, class Function>
class Map {
private:
    Function fun;
public:
    Map() {}
    Map(Function f):fun(f) {}


    std::vector<Tout> operator()(bool use_tbb, std::vector<Tin>& v) {
        std::vector<Tout> r(v.size());
        if(use_tbb){
            // Start measuring time
            auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<Tin>(0, v.size()),
                        [&](tbb::blocked_range<Tin> t) {
                    for (int index = t.begin(); index < t.end(); ++index){
                        r[index] = fun(v[index]);
                    }
            });
            // Stop measuring time and calculate the elapsed time
            auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - begin);
            printf("Time measured: %.3f seconds.\n", elapsed.count() * 1e-9);
            return r;
         } else {
                sycl::queue gpuQueue{sycl::gpu_selector()};
                sycl::range<1> n_item{v.size()};
                sycl::buffer<Tin, 1> in_buffer(&v[0], n_item);
                sycl::buffer<Tout, 1> out_buffer(&r[0], n_item);
                gpuQueue.submit([&](sycl::handler& h){
                    //local copy of fun
                    auto f = fun;
                    sycl::accessor in_accessor(in_buffer, h, sycl::read_only);
                    sycl::accessor out_accessor(out_buffer, h, sycl::write_only);
                    h.parallel_for(n_item, [=](sycl::id<1> index) {
                        out_accessor[index] = f(in_accessor[index]);
                    });
                }).wait();
         }
                return r;
    }
};

template<class Tin, class Tout, class Function>
Map<Tin, Tout, Function> make_map(Function f) { return Map<Tin, Tout, Function>(f);}


typedef int(*func)(int x);
//define different functions
auto function = [](int x){ return x; };
auto functionTimesTwo = [](int x){ return (x*2); };
auto functionDivideByTwo = [](int x){ return (x/2); };
auto lambdaFunction = [](int x){return (++x);};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    //auto f = [](int x){return (++x);};
    //Array of functions
    func functions[] =
        {
            function,
            functionTimesTwo,
            functionDivideByTwo,
            lambdaFunction
        };

    for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(functions); i++){
        auto m1 = make_map<int, int>(functions[i]);

    //auto m1 = make_map<int, int>(f);
    std::vector<int> r = m1(true, v);
    //print the result
    for(auto &e:r) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
        }
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way do you not know how to use it? What have you tried? It would improve your question if you specifically described the problem you are having with the tool you linked to. I would also suggest an issue on the repository as a better way to find out where the instructions are to use the tool if you cannot find them.

Comment: In fact, I do not know how can I use them. for example about Utimer, I know I should use it like:    {Utimer // line of my code which I want to understand the execution time}. but about that link I do not know where I should put in my code and how use them.

Comment: This question is too open ended, take a look at the guidelines for questions on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask I'd recommend narrowing your question to a specific issue you are having.

Comment: Basic description of how to measure kernel execution time in SYCL/DPC++ is here: https://github.com/intel/pti-gpu/blob/master/chapters/device_activity_tracing/DPCXX.md. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, SYCL Kernel wont support function pointers. So, you can change the code accordingly.

One way to achieve profiling in GPU is by following the steps below:
1.Enable profiling mode for the command queue of the target device
2.Introduce the event for the target device activity
3.Set the callback to be notified when the activity is completed
4.Read the profiling data inside the callback

Basically, you need to use CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START and CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END (command identified by event start and end execution on the device) inside the call back.

You can find the detailed steps here
https://github.com/intel/pti-gpu/blob/master/chapters/device_activity_tracing/OpenCL.md

I would also advice you to check the samples for pti-gpu using Device Activity Tracing. Check the URL for the same
https://github.com/intel/pti-gpu/tree/master/samples